# What might cause ruby to lock up while exiting?

Tags: ruby, locking, exit

I have a ruby script that does a few perforce operations (through the scripting API) then simply ends:

```
def foo()
  ...
end

def bar()
  ...
end

foo()
bar()
puts __LINE__
exit 0
#end of file
```

...and while the **LINE** will print out, the process never ends, whether the exit(0) is there or not.  This is ruby 1.8.6, primarily on the mac, but I'm seeing this on the PC as well.

I'm doing the usual google poking around, but hoped there might be a voice of experience here to bank on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with perforce, but the culprit might be an [`at_exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005932) method that's stuck in a loop for some reason.  Observe the behavior using `irb`, for instance:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'time'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> at_exit { puts Time.now; sleep 10; puts Time.now }
=> #<Proc:0xb7656f64@(irb):2>
irb(main):003:0> exit
Fri Mar 12 19:46:25 -0500 2010
Fri Mar 12 19:46:35 -0500 2010
```

To confirm whether an `at_exit` function is causing the process to hang, you can try hooking into `at_exit`.  Note that the `#{caller}` will display the stack trace of who called `at_exit`:

```
def at_exit &block
    @at_exit_counter ||= 0
    puts "at_exit #{@at_exit_counter} called"
    s = "Calling at_exit ##{@at_exit_counter} from #{caller}"
    super { puts s; block.call() }
    @at_exit_counter += 1
end

at_exit { puts "I'll never return"; sleep 1 while true; }
at_exit { puts 'I am about to leave.' }

def do_cleanup
    puts "Cleaning..."
    at_exit { puts 'Cleaning up before exit...' }

end

do_cleanup
```

which outputs:

```
at_exit 0 called
at_exit 1 called
Cleaning...
at_exit 2 called
Calling at_exit #2 from exitcheck.rb:14:in `do_cleanup'exitcheck.rb:18
Cleaning up before exit...
Calling at_exit #1 from exitcheck.rb:10
I am about to leave.
Calling at_exit #0 from exitcheck.rb:9
I'll never return
```

and never returns.